# How do I prevent term from being created on create_term hook?

Tags: hooks, actions, terms

I have a function working on 'create_term' hook, I'm trying to prevent 
the term from being created on certain situations, I've tried

```
return false;
```

But that didn't do much, how do I prevent the term from being created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create_term` as you can see in [inline docs in code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/17b17d1c78bc2617ee31de6f9ef962c2eacbb716/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2547)

> Fires immediately after a new term is created, before the term cache
>   is cleaned

So you can't prevent an event after that event already happen.

To prevent a term is inserted you can use [**`'pre_insert_term'`** filter hook](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/17b17d1c78bc2617ee31de6f9ef962c2eacbb716/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2420) and return a `WP_Error` a `0` or an empty string.

Example:

```
add_filter( 'pre_insert_term', 'prevent_add_term', 20, 2 );

function prevent_add_term( $term, $taxonomy ) {
  if ( $term === 'i-am-a-bad-term' ) {
    $term = new WP_Error( 'invalid_term', 'Term you tried to add sucks' );
  }
  return $term;
}
```

Comment: good, concise, and I wish the docs would've covered hooks a bit better.

Comment: @Asaf all of us hope that ;)

Answer (score 1):

`create_term` is only fired after the term has already been inserted, so returning false will do nothing.

`pre_insert_term` appears to be the hook to use, as mentioned in the [codex here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term#Hooks_Used). However, the specific hook seems undocumented, so you might have to play with it a bit.

Comment: Aaand see G.M.'s simultaneous answer, more thorough than mine.